# Modify content in Gutenberg editor using JavaScript

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Earlier with TinyMCE it was easy to modify content by just modifying the content in HTML as TinyMCE was attached to fixed 'div id="content"'

How can the content be modified using JavaScript in Gutenberg?

I tried to modify using the same way I used to do in TinyMCE but that just modifies the content in HTML and not the actual content in Gutenberg

I fetched the content from Gutenberg blocks using the following code.

```
  public getContent(): string {
    const editor = wp.data.select('core/editor');
    let content = '';
    if (editor) {
      const editedContent = editor.getEditedPostContent();
      const blocks = wp.blocks.parse(editedContent) as any as Block[];
      if (blocks && blocks.length > 0) {
        blocks.forEach((block) => {
          content += this.createGutenbergBlock(block);
        });
      }
    }
    return '<blocks>' + content + '</blocks>' ;
  }

 private createGutenbergBlock(block: Block): string {
    const innerblocks = block.innerBlocks.map((blk) => {
      return this.createGutenbergBlock(blk);
    }).join('');
    return `<block 
    clientId="${block.clientId}">${block.originalContent}${innerblocks} 
    </block>`;
  }
```

I'm wondering how I can modify the content of a block in Gutenberg using JavaScript?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I was wondering the same thing.